# How is the sweep type affecting the Bode plots for the same AC analysis in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, passive-networks, frequency-response

When I do an AC analysis for the following circuit between 0.1Hz upto 20MHz, and by selecting "decade" in sweep types I obtain the following plots:

[image]

But if I do exactly the same thing only this time I set the seep type to "linear" I get some sort of unusual plot:

[image]

I couldn't find information about these different sweep types.

Why am I having different plots for the same AC analysis with different sweep types?

Comment: A linear sweep doesn't make any sense over that wide of a dynamic range. It produces only a very few data points at low frequency and lots of then at high. So it has to interpolate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type gives you the amount of points where values are calculated, and how they are distributed. Then in the plot they are connected by lines.

Using 10000 points linear over 20Mhz gives a point each 2kHz, which seems to be about right given your plot and start frequency.

The first half of your plot is just two points then because it is plotting logarithmic